# Vue-loader deep selector with direct child

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-loader

I have a tab component, that has other tabs inside like this

```
<tabs :class="{ 'my-class': ifTrue }">
    <tab v-for="tab in tabs">
        ...
    </tab>
    <tab-item v-for="tab in tabs">
        <tabs :class="{ 'my-class': ifTrue }">
            <tab v-for="tab in tabs">
                ...
            </tab>
            <tab-item v-for="tab in tabs">
                ...
            </tab-item>
        </tab>
    </tab-item>
</tab>

<style scoped>
    .no-tabs >>> .tab {
        display: none
    }
</style>
```

From the component where i use the `tabs` i want to hide the direct child `tab` if it has the class, the problem is that when i apply the class like above, it will hide the `tab` in the `tab-item` as well, i want to just hide the direct tab child. Something like

```
In css would be 
.no-tabs > .tab

But in vue i try this but wont work.

.no-tabs >>> > .tab
or
.no-tabs > >>> .tab
```

but neither of those worked, How can i access only the first tab direct child `.tab` ?

I can't edit the `tabs` component, that's why i don't do it directly there.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

Comment: The problem is pure css: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

Comment: Are you attempting to give an element `display: none` and, at the same time, have it display some of its DOM children? If that is what you're asking, you should note it is not technically possible. The only solution is to get the contents you need displayed outside of the content with `display: none`.

Comment: @Phil no, i want to get the direct child no first child.
@DavidGard can't use pure css, as the `scoped` attribute in vue add a dynamic attribute so the css wont apply
@AndreiGheorghiu No, the `tab` is the header and the `tab-item` is the content, i want do `display:none` the `tab` the content of the tab will still be visible in the `tab-item` but when i use `.no-tabs >>> .tab` this will also apply the `display: none` to the sub-tabs header, and i just want to hide the parent `tab`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the the vue-loader was not understanding this form

`.no-tabs >>> > .tab`

Using this from worked for me

`.no-tabs /deep/ > .tab`